# How to Import image from IBM cloud object storage using IBM CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-storage

We need to import image from .vmdk file existing in the IBM Cloud Object Storage through IBM CLI.

I did not find any documents with the command for importing the image. Please help me with the command to do the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "importing"? Download? Integrate into another system? ...?

Answer (score 0):

Importing a custom image is not available through the CLI.
You can import using the python client Image Manager though.
https://softlayer-api-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/managers/image/

More background here
https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/speed-up-image-imports-to-ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

IBM Clouds Object Storage (ICOS) allows you to make the bucket contents public so that it can be queried. You'll have to do that through the 'Access Policies' tab. Once done, selecting 'Object Details' on an object in your ICOS bucket will reveal the public URL which can then be used in the image form (CLI)... or the Dialog section of Watson Assistant.